# fullscreen background images

Tags: jquery, css

I've already got a background image. But i'm builid a gallery which would have different categories. If i select a category the images would load up in little squares and then when i select any of them i  want it to change a named id's content...[image]

e.g.

Any good tips would be appreciated immensely.

What i'm trying to do are two items.

1. Change the color of the navigation box to a solid color.
2. change the image source of an id "grouptabs" when clicked

   `<div id="random">
       <img id="grouptabs" src="/u/i/1920x1200.jpg" />
   </div>`

This is what i'm trying to get to...
Thanks for all your suggestions

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  I think you'll have more luck getting an answer if you try to rework your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is what you're looking for:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't execute the link
  $(.thumbnail').css('background-color', 'none'); // reset all BG colors
  $(this).css('background-color', '#00FF00'); // fill BG of clicked elements parent (the p-element).

  var imghref = $(this).attr('href'); // get the image src from the href
  $('#grouptabs').attr('src', imghref);  // set the image src for #grouptabs
});
```

This works with a setup like:

1
     2
     3
     4

So the image is being loaded in grouptab (the full size). In CSS you should specify that an a-element within class thumbnails is having a border and no bgcolor. The BG color is handled by the jquery click event.

Hopefully this helps.

// `EDIT`: try this:

```
$('.crafty').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.foliolist').css('background-color', 'transparant'); // set all foliolist items bg color to transparant
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
  $('#grouptabs').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I'm not sure if you are using this setup:

```
<div class="foliolist"><a href="img/dir/file.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="foliolist"><a href="img/dir/file.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="foliolist"><a href="img/dir/file.jpg"></a></div>
```

or

```
<div class="foliolist">
  <a href="img/dir/file.jpg"></a>
  <a href="img/dir/file.jpg"></a>
  <a href="img/dir/file.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Because there is a difference. In the first case my scripts works. In the second, you need the style (background-color) applied to $(this) instead of $(this).parent()

Comment: My question was a bit off i was lierally asleep on my keyboard when i typed it out.

What i'm trying to do are two items.

Comment: Sorry for that i was not looking when i hit return...

What i'm trying to do are two items.

1. Change the color of the navigation box to a solid color.

2. change the image source of an id when clicked


 
 <div id="random">
  <img id="grouptabs" src="/uploads/images/yakushima_forest_1920x1200.jpg" />
 </div>

Comment: Sorry for that i was not looking when i hit return...

What i'm trying to do are two items.

1. Change the color of the navigation box to a solid color.

2. change the image source of an id "grouptabs" when clicked


 
 `<div id="random">
  <img id="grouptabs" src="/u/i/1920x1200.jpg" />
 </div>`

Thanks

Comment: `$('#random').css('background-color', '#00FF00');` (insert own color) and `$('#grouptabs').attr('src', 'new/source/here.jpg');`

Comment: Thanks for that, how would i write it out before i loop through my 20 items. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can add a default css style to all boxes and upon a click reset all styles to just a border (and perhaps a default BG/loading BG) and then set the clicked element's css to a full color and set the bg.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to show me an example, that would be great if you don't mind..Thanks

Comment: I wish I could, but I don't fully understand the setup of your HTML file, if you could add that to your question and explain what element is being clicked on and what elements should be changed, I will.

Comment: I tried to make a setup for you, see my editted answer. If this is not what you need, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Pendo here's how i display the nav boxes...

`<div class="foliolist"><a title="crafty" href="/u/i/1200.jpg"></a></div>`

Comment: `<div class="foliolist"><a title="crafty" href="/u/i/1200.jpg"></a></div>`

I guess what i'm trying to say is how do i call the function from the above html. Thnaks for all your help.

Comment: Okay i now get it, it's working (partially) the nav bars get changed, but the image that doesn't change. If i specify one physically it does work. This portion is whats playing up....    `var imghref = $(this).attr('href'); // get the image src from the href
    $('#grouptabs').attr('src', imghref);  // set the image src for #grouptabs` Thanks!!

Comment: you might wanna try an `alert(imghref);` and see what that does right between both lines. If the src is correct, perhaps there's a problem with the location of the file (maybe it should be ../u/i/1200.jpg or something).

Comment: You could also try `window.location(imghref);` and see if the image shows up.

Comment: alert came up as undefined. but when i use `.foliolist a` it shows the correct path but it doesn't cycle to the next link item when clicked..Thanks for your help

Comment: can you shouw me your code? It should be similar to `$(".crafty").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var imghref = $(this).attr('href'); $('#grouptabs').attr('src', imghref); });`

Comment: My code attached....  `$('.foliolist').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't execute the link
    $('.foliolist').css('background-color', 'transparent'); // reset all BG colors
    $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF'); // fill BG of clicked elements parent (the p-element).
  
    var imghref = $(this).attr('href'); // get the image src from the href
    alert(imghref);
    $('#grouptabs').attr("src", imghref);  // set the image src for #grouptabs
  });`

Comment: If i take off the following lines for the css it works.

`$('.foliolist').css('background-color', 'transparent'); $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF'); `

Comment: Ok, as I can so you are trying to put the click action on the foliolist div instead of the crafty a-element. by $(this).attr('href') you are now refering to the href of the div, which isn't set(!). I'm putting a new code in my answer for you to test.

Comment: Thanks for your help once again. crafty is a title element set on the href inside the foliolist div.

`#folioholder`
  `.foliolist` then the link href

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine. Can you post your complete HTML (or online demo) file at pastebin.org perhaps? So I can see the exact layout and I can get the correct script for you.

Comment: I put in the following code and it worked perfectly...`$('.foliolist a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.foliolist a').css('background-color', 'transparent'); // set all foliolist items bg color to transparant
  $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
  $('#grouptabs').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
});
;
`
There's just a slight issue with the css other than that i appreciate all your help. If i can help you out please feel free to ask!

Comment: Just out of curiousity how can i activate/select the first item in the list without clicking?? Thanks

Comment: Depends on your code. Usually you can use something linke $('.foliolist a:first') and add the code, Perhaps you need $('.foliolist:first') and then select the first a-element.

Answer (score 1):

say you have stored the background information on the category. like for example through jQuery.data()

Then all you need to do is

```
$('.category').click(function(){
  var thisElem = $(this)
  $('#myBackround').css({background-image:"url('"+thisElem.data('backgroundImagePath')+"')"})
})
```

This example shows how you can change the background image of a dom element. However, if you want to change the content then you can use `jQuery.html()` instead of `jQuery.css()`

As a side note , you can also set the currently clicked category another opacity level in order to show that this is the selected element.

then you would do something like this instead:

```
$('.category').click(function(){
  var thisElem = $(this)
  //remove active effect on any previously selected categories
  thisElem.siblings().removeClass('activeCategory')
  //add active effect to currently selected category
  thisElem.addClass('activeCategory')

  $('#myBackround').css({
        background-image:"url('"+thisElem.data('backgroundImagePath')+"')"
  })

})
```

Where you could have the css property

```
.activeCategory {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #f60;
}
```